# Reconstructing zlib stream

Tags: stream, compression, zlib

My project contains a Sender/Receiver framework that can only talk one-way , there is no a return channel from the receiver to the sender.
The sender compress part of the data it's send to the receiver using zlib.

I want to make my receiver resilient to crashes/reboots/restarts, is it possible to join the zlib stream from a random point somehow?

Both Sender/Receiver using Z_SYNC_FLUSH.

Some ideas I had:

1. Saving state structures to disk and reload them after restart of the receiver.
2. Replacing Z_SYNC_FLUSH to Z_FULL_FLUSH.

I tried saving the first chunk of zlib compressed data, restart the receiver and than resend the first chunk again and after that continue the stream from a random chunk and it seems to work - I don't understand why, is it a solid solution or it was just a luck?

Replacing to Z_FULL_FLUSH didn't seem to make any difference.

Is there another way to work around this? Do you think I missed something?

Thanks a lot,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assure that you can start decompression at some point with no history, you must either use `Z_FULL_FLUSH` or simply end the stream and start a new one.

For the former you could do a `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` followed by a `Z_FULL_FLUSH` in order to insert two markers resulting in the nine bytes `00 00 ff ff 00 00 00 ff ff`, which would be unlikely to be seen randomly in the compressed data. You can do the same for the latter, simply inserting a large-enough marker between the end of the previous zlib stream and the start of the next zlib stream.

Comment: I can't ask the sender to end the stream and start a new one because the sender connected to the receiver via unidirectional link, the sender can't know that the receiver restarted and needs a fresh stream.


I retried Z_FULL_FLUSH , I'm getting Z_DATA_ERROR with "incorrect header check" , I tried to call InflateSync() after getting Z_DATA_ERROR from Inflate() , InflateSync() return Z_OK but Inflate() returns the same errors.

Comment: If you are not in control of the sending side, then there is no way to restart in the middle of the stream. `Z_FULL_FLUSH` only has meaning to `deflate()`, not `inflate()`.

Comment: Thank you Mark,
Do you have an explanation how the scenario I described In my question is possible? I'm taking the first chunk of the stream ( the first output of deflate() )  and send it to the receiver after it restarted and then pick a random chunk from the stream and send it to the receiver too. 
The random chunk inflated successfully, how is it possible? If I'm not wrong, the inflate function is looking for sequences from previous data that in this case is missing.

Comment: I could not understand your description of the scenario in your question. You need to consider what "successful" means. If you are breaking a deflate stream in the middle and feeding random data after that, then for some distance it may indeed continue to be "successful" in that it will not immediately return an error. However it will be generating junk, and will eventually fail when a block end code is accidentally encountered, and the next block is gibberish.

Comment: If I can guarantee that only valid zlib blocks are passed to inflate() after the receiver restarted and if I can tolerate that the decompression of the first few blocks will be invalid, should it work for the long run? If I'm not wrong the WindowSize is by default 32K , that means that after 32K at max the decompression should be valid again. In my tests, It also looks fine.

Comment: No. There can always be references to references of any length, stringing all the way back to the unknown data.